# How to load JMS configuration from a .bindings file in Spring

Tags: java, spring, binding, ibm-mq, jndi

I am still new with Spring and Ibm/mq but I am using JMSTemplate in a Spring project (build with maven) to send messages to a MQ. It works fine when I use the application.propeties file to define the MQ server infos.

Now I am triyng to do the same with a ".bindings", the binding file that I generated from my MQ server. It has lines like: `QUEUE_CONNECTION_FACTORY_NAME/ClassName=com.ibm.mq.jms.MyQueueConnectionFactory`

- Can I use JMSTemplate to load the configuration from that binding file? How?

What I know is that the main way to use this file is with a JNDI FSContext, But I did not find how:

- Where do you put the .bindings file?
- How do you load it? (and do you load from a bean xml or from a context in the java code)

Is it even possible? I saw some old messages on a board saying that: "Spring does not support a .binding file. Any configuration items in the .binding file need to be translated into the appropriate Spring XML configuration."

In the other side I have this that have an incomplete answer to my question:
[How to load JNDI context from the file system into Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48253047/how-to-load-jndi-context-from-the-file-system-into-spring)

I have an overload of information but not a simple how to do this.

EDIT:
Now I can load the content of the file but it seems not compatible.
My code is like this:

```
environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory");
environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "file:/Users/user/jndi");

Context mycontext = new InitialContext( environment );
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) mycontext.lookup("QCONNECTION_FACTORY");

JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
MQQueue dest = (MQQueue) mycontext.lookup("LQ1");

//Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection("***","***");
//Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(dest, "hello");
```

My queue jndi info:

```
LQ1/RefAddr/12/Type=MDCTX
LQ1/RefAddr/12/Encoding=String
LQ1/RefAddr/12/Content=0
LQ1/RefAddr/16/Content=LQ1
LQ1/RefAddr/16/Type=QU
```

and the JMSAdmin script:

```
DEF Q(LQ1) QUEUE(LQ1)
def qcf(QCONNECTION_FACTORY)transport(CLIENT)channel(DEV.APP.CHANNEL)host(localhost)port(1414)qmgr(QM1)
end
```

But I am getting:

```
org.springframework.jms.JmsSecurityException: JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue 'LQ1'.; nested exception is com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue 'LQ1'
JMS attempted to perform an MQOPEN, but IBM MQ reported an error.
Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error. Check that the specified queue and queue manager are defined correctly.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').
```

Comment: Does this help?  https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-spring4/index.html

Comment: @JoshMc Tried. But it seems that it is too outdated and can't make their "jmstemplate102" work.

Comment: @chughts maybe this would be a good tutorial to take on for https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-patterns/

Comment: @JoshMc Now I have acces to binding file content using lookup, and end up like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42248917/ibm-mq-issue-jmsmq1113-the-destination-does-not-have-a-name-set I will edit this post.

Comment: Now you are at a different error all together.  2035 is a as it says NOT AUTHORIZED error.  This is very generic since it is not good practice to send back specific of what went wrong security wise to a client.  You will need to check the queue managers `AMQERR01.LOG` to find out why it failed.  It could be that you are failing to connect to the queue manager or it could be that you lack permission to the queue itself.

Comment: I suggest if you can't figure it out from my comment above that you open a new question specific to the 2035 issue and provide what the qmgr logs provide you. I think the original problem faced in this question has been addressed by the question you and I linked to.  You can write up what solved it for you here as a self answer.

Comment: My error was from the ibm/mq version it seems. I will answer this post when I finish and have a clear vision.